Getting error in ASP.NET Core web app in Blazor with auto mode
Sometimes I get below error in the browser. I need to clear cache for my site then it start working again.
I don't know why....
I have a solution in .NET Core with the following projects:

Fbnt.Maui - Blazor Hybrid Maui
Fbnt.Web - Blazor WebApp also used as API
Fbnt.Web.Client - Blazor WebApp Client
Fbnt.SharedRCL - Razor class library sharing common UI between web and Maui.
Fbnt.Domain - Class library project for Domain Definition of Clean Architecture.
Fbnt.Application - Class library project for Application layer of Clean Architecture.
Fbnt.Infrastructure - Class library project for Infrastructure layer of Clean Architecture.

Ensure that Fbnt.SharedRCL - Razor class library shares a common UI between web and Maui.
Error:

AggregateException_ctor_DefaultMessage (Root component type 'Fbnt.SharedRCL.Components.Layout.Shared.HeaderControl' could not be found in the assembly 'Fbnt.SharedRCL'.)
at Jn (dotnet.runtime.8.0.3.76cp6ozpzf.js:3:31614)
at xl (dotnet.runtime.8.0.3.76cp6ozpzf.js:3:182162)
at 00b217ca:0x1fa8f
at 00b217ca:0x1bf5a
at 00b217ca:0xf141
at 00b217ca:0x1e7a9
at 00b217ca:0x1ef9f
at 00b217ca:0xcfbb
at 00b217ca:0x4412f
at e. (dotnet.runtime.8.0.3.76cp6ozpzf.js:3:215234)

I just don't want this error.
As I need to live this site..
Should I convert it to server only or webassembly only will solved that issue?

About this error:

AggregateException_ctor_DefaultMessage (Root component type
'...........' could not be
found in the assembly '...........'.)

You can refer to this case: Blazor application shows error in console when Auto mode is used.

Any interactive components (which is what you are making Routes by
setting its RenderMode to Auto) must be moved to the
webassembly/client project in RC1.
This is required because Routes must now be built in WASM and sent
to the browser as part of the webassembly bits.

Hope it can help you.

I have added all components in Fbnt.SharedRCL razor class library. and it have render mode Auto. I have added its referace in Fbnt.Web.Client also by using this ducument

It's werid, is it the reason for using Clean Architecture?
